# Log my battery performance on netbook

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp

Which Windows API (Windows Xp and Window 7) do I use to log my battery performance on netbook? I want to write an app which can graph the watt vs time. I always run a select few apps on the netbook. Is there a tool for this already?

Comment: take a look at this question... it might help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724349/how-can-i-measure-the-energy-consumption-of-my-application-on-windows-mobile-and

Comment: @sebastian - that's a Windows Mobile question -- this one is about (non-Mobile) windows. AFAIK, power support is handled differently in each OS.  I'd suggest leaving this question open.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows DDK tool [`PwrTest /BATTERY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa906541.aspx) emits a [log file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa906545.aspx) including all the info you are looking for. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa906541.aspx):

> The PwrTest Battery scenario is
>   designed to facilitate automated
>   inspection of battery and power source
>   information. PwrTest is capable of
>   logging battery capacity, voltage,
>   rate of drain and general state for up
>   to two batteries on the system.
>   Battery data is logged at a specified
>   interval for a specified number of
>   cycles.

I'm not sure if this tool works on XP, but it's easy to download the DDK and try the tool on XP.

Comment: The latest DDK is here : http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2105564e-1a9a-4bf4-8d74-ec5b52da3d00&displaylang=en ... says "Version 7.0.0 contains the tools, code samples, documentation, compilers, headers and libraries with which software developers create drivers for Windows 7, Windows Vista, Windows XP, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008, and Windows Server 2003" .Supported Operating Systems for Kit Installation : Windows XP Service Pack 3